# Adobe Acrobat 11: how to select, move, edit objects

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, vector-graphics

In Acrobat 9 pro, there was this neat little tool Edit Object (Touch Up), that gave you the possibility, to click on separate words of text while holding CTRL, and when the selection was made, then you could move it, rescale it, rotate it.

I have a file in which in a single row of text some words are not horizontally aligned. I'd like to fix that, by choosing two words and move them a bit higher. How can I do that.

Also: in Acrobat 9 pro, if I colored the letters of a word differently, then I could select specific letters of a word and move them around. I could also move a selection outside of the visible page. How can I do all this in Acrobat 11 pro?

I hate it when a new version comes out and it's crappier than the ones before it. Is 10 similar to 11 or 9?

Comment: Also, where is the tool to change the numbering of pages?

Comment: Acrobat 10 is more similar to 9, Edit Object works as it should.